# SQL Grouped time calculation

Tags: sql

I want to solve a calculation problem in SQL. I have z. B. Machines and bookings:

```
Machine|Time
--------------
     1 |08:00
     1 |08:10
     2 |08:15
     1 |09:00
     2 |09:15
```

Now I would like to have the time per machine as a result.

For 1:

```
08:00 - 08:10 (10 min.), 08:10 - to 08:15 (5 min.).
```

For 2

```
08:15 - 09:00 (45 min.)
```

The last time has no subsequent end.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: why your output is not including 3rd time slot of id 1 i,e; `9:00 to 9:15`. In fact what is the logic of including 2 machine id in single calculation. Please check that again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LEAD()` if your DB is SQL Server

```
SELECT Machine
    ,[Time] 
    ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[Time] ,LEAD([Time]) OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) ) AS [Time (In Minute)]
FROM (VALUES(1,'08:00'),(1,'08:10'),(2,'08:15'),(1,'09:00'),(2,'09:15')) A(Machine,[Time])
```